# How to make a replaced image fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have been playing with a script that replaces an image from a low quality version to a high quality version, the replace is working fine, however, I need the replaced image to fade in slowly rather than being instantly replaced as it is now.

```
//For each of the images in the class
$(".image-to-be-reloaded").each(function (i, classReturn) {

    var image = classReturn.firstChild; //Gets the image for that element


    //Get the original source
    var originalSource = image.src;

    //Replaces the preview within the query string to use the high quality version.
    var finishedSource = //My replace method goes here

    image.src = finishedSource; //Update the image src


    $(classReturn).replaceWith(image).fadeIn(10000);

});
```

The fadeIn that I am using isn't being executed though the preceding text definitely is, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a way to achieve what I was trying to do using the following snippet.

```
$(classReturn).replaceWith(function () {
    return $(image).hide().fadeIn(4000);
});
```